# How to use scala switch statement for a class

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a function in scala that will return a `Boolean` based on several case statements

```
def my_func(result : Result) : Boolean = {
  labResult match {
    case (result.name == "test" && result.value >= 10) => false
    //more case statements
  }
}
```

But I'm getting a compile error on the `&&`. What is the way to accomplish this?

Comment: Note that it's not a `switch`. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use guard with extractor

```
case class Result(name: String, value: Int)

def my_func(result: Result): Boolean = result match {
 case Result(name, value) if name == "test" && value >= 10 => false
}
```

you can take equality condition into extractor

```
def my_func(result: Result): Boolean = result match {
 case Result("test", value) if value >= 10 => false
}
```

Its not switch its called as Pattern matching in Scala jargon. Above code is the idiomatic Scala code which has Pattern matching guard with extractor.

Don't forget to give the case where the condition does not hold if not you will get Match Error

```
case class Result(name: String, value: Int)

def my_func(result: Result): Boolean = result match {
 case Result(name, value) if name == "test" && value >= 10 => false
 case _ => true //if above condition fails to match 
}
```

If you have extra params then use `_` to ignore

```
case class Result(name: String, value: Int, foo: Int)

def my_func(result: Result): Boolean = result match {
  case Result(name, value, _) if name == "test" && value >= 10 => false
  case _ => true //if above condition fails to match 
}
```

In the above code we are ignoring foo by using `_`.

*Note we can use multiple `_` to ignore multiple parameters. we can use `_` in between as well like this `Result(name, _, foo)`. Here we are ignoring `value` parameter*

If `Result` is not a `case class` then Parameter extraction during pattern matching does not work So you have to write a Custom extractor for Result class.

*Note Scala compiler writes a extractor for you in case of case class. In case of normal class we have to write extractor for pattern matching with extracted parameters to work*

```
class Result (val name: String, val value: Int, val foo: Int)

object Result {
  def unapply(result: Result): Option[(String, Int, Int)] = Some((result.name, result.value, result.foo))
}

def my_func(result: Result): Boolean = result match {
  case Result(name, value, _) if name == "test" && value >= 10 => false
  case _ => true //if above condition fails to match 
}
```

Comment: What if the case class had three attributes: `name, value, somethingelse` but in `my_func` I only cared about `name,value`. Would the code for `my_func` be any different?

Comment: @Omnipresent You can match only on the variables you care about and fill in an underscore where you don't, i.e.: `case Result(name, value, _) =>`

Comment: I've submitted an edit for review adding the possibility to write custom extractor; meanwhile you can read more about them here: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html

Comment: Be careful when using `guards` - https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/714125150711451648.

Comment: @Omnipresent Note, that usually you can integrate equality tests into the pattern: `result match { case Result("test", value, _) if value >= 10 => false }`

Answer (score 1):

Use a guard:

```
def myFunc(result: Result): Boolean = {
  result match {
    case _ if (result.name == "test" && result.value >= 10) => false
  }
}
```

Note that if you use this approach, your match statements need to be exhaustive and match all cases.

Or you can go about without pattern matching, using simple boolean logic:

```
def myFunc(result: Result): Boolean = {
  (result.name != "test" || result.value < 10) ||
  (result.name == "other" && result.value >= 42)    
}
```

Comment: Don't you think that such a pattern should be discouraged ?

Comment: For the guard option you are using `_`. What if I had more than one case statements? Would I write each one with `case _ if (...) => true` ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh You know what, I'm not sure. I wouldn't write such code, but it's definitely an option. It's a matter of style really. I would probably use an `if-else` expression.

Comment: @Omnipresent You could if you wanted to. You can use multiple `_` to ignore the parameter.

Comment: Pun intended? :D Wrapping the thing in an Option look like an overkill to me and furthermore: how would you add cases?

Comment: @stefanobaghino Removed that, thought about it and a definite overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the pattern matching the wrong way. You have to focus on the word `pattern` in pattern-matching.

What you need to do is,

```
def my_func(result : Result) : Boolean = {
  result match {
    case r if (r.name == "test" && r.value >= 10) => false
    //more case statements
  }
}
```

Here, the think of part `r if (r.name == "test" && r.value >= 10)` as a pattern in itself.